# How to add items to a list from List<IEnumerable> using C# Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

I have a List T , and I have a List of IEnumerable query.
I want to add the selection/ all the values of List of IEnumerable to this List T.
I tried below but it shows error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'List IEnumerable ' to a generic list Reason.

I am very new to LINQ, please guide. I tried the following :

```
public class Reason
{
public int ReasonId { get; set; }
public int OrderId { get; set; }
}


 var newReason = new List<Reason>();

 newReason = reasons?.Select(res => res.Select(re => new Reason()
                    {
                        ReasonId  = re.ReasonId,
                        OrderId = re.OrderId,
                    })).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the type of `reasons`? Do you really need `.Select(... Select(...))`

Comment: class declaration doesn't have `()`

Comment: Type of reasons? is List<IEnumerable<>>

Comment: @AnnSnow, If the type of `reasons?` variable is `List<IEnumerable<>>` then you need [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0) not select inside select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create list of `Reason` instance by flattening nested `reasons` list, try [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0)

```
 newReason = reasons?.SelectMany(re => new Reason()
                    {
                        ReasonId  = re.ReasonId,
                        OrderId = re.OrderId,
                    })?.ToList()
                    ?? new List<Reason>();
```

---

`Select()` inside `Select()` will return `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Reason>>`, and you need flatten list of `Reason` class i.e. `List<Reason>` so use `SelectMany()`

Comment: yes it worked, Thanks much ! Through after using SelectMany is showing a null reference possibility, for re

Comment: Either you can filter `reasons` list to get only non null reason instance or if you want instance for null records also, then you can use null coalescing operator while assigning properties